# The Borel(-Tanner) distribution - explanation

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

I'm interested in understanding the Borel distribution. It is hard to find an explanation accessible for someone with undergraduate knowledge, therefore I'm looking for help here. As Wikipedia describes, this distribution is given by the pmf:
$$P_\mu(X = n) = \frac{(\mu n)^{n-1}}{n! \cdot e^{\mu n}}.$$
What is the motivation for this definition? How can one prove that $\sum_{n=1}^\infty P(X = n)$ is indeed equal to $1$ (looking at the formula, it's not obvious)? However the biggest problem that I encounter is to truely understand what is really going on.

> If the number of offspring that an organism has is Poisson-distributed, and if the average number of offspring of each organism is no bigger than 1, then the descendants of each individual will ultimately become extinct. The number of descendants that an individual ultimately has in that situation is a random variable distributed according to a Borel distribution.

Assume that the number of offsprings is Poison-distributed with $\lambda = 2$. What will be the corresponding $\mu$ parameter?

Comment: $\lambda$ in Poisson distribution should be an integer, because $\lambda \approx np$ from Binomial distribution

Comment: Why should lambda be an integer? Note that for lambda = 2, the branching process explodes with a positive probability.

Comment: Re the main question, the crux of the matter is that the distribution of the total progeny $N$ of a Poisson branching process of parameter $\lambda\lt1$ solves the distributional identity $u(s)=\exp(\lambda(u(s)-1))$ where $u(s)=E(s^N)$. On the other hand, using that every Borel distribution has mass $1$, one gets that, if $X$ is Borel $\mu$ then $E(s^X)=\mu(s)/\mu$ where $\mu(s)$ solves $sf(\mu)=f(\mu(s))$, where $f(\mu)=\mu e^{-\mu}$. By some algebra, these are equivalent if $\lambda$ solves $f(\lambda)=f(\mu)$, that is, $\lambda=\mu$ if $\mu\lt1$ and $\lambda$ the other root if $\mu\gt1$.